# An (Incorrect) Solution to Problem 20(b) in Chapter 3 of Spivak's Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

So, I've been self-studying Spivak, which has been a joy, though a frustrating one at times. Below is one of many problems that I found difficult. I believe my attempted solution is lacking and want to know if it can be salvaged.

Suppose that $f(y)-f(x) \le (y-x)^2$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R.$ Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

Without loss of generality, suppose $x < y.$ The hint is to partition the interval into $n$ equal pieces. Define $\Delta x = (y-x)/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N.$ Let $x_i = x+i \Delta x$ for all $i \in \\{ 0, \dots, n-1 \\}.$ Then, we have that
$$f(x_i+\Delta x)-f(x_i) \le \Delta x^2.$$
Suppose that $f(x_i+\Delta x)-f(x_i) \neq 0.$ Substituting and rearranging,
$$\frac{f(x_i+\Delta x)-f(x_i)}{(y-x)^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n}.$$
However, by the Archimedean property, there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$\frac{1}{n} < \frac{f(x_i+\Delta x)-f(x_i)}{(y-x)^2},$$
which is a contradiction. Thus, $f(x_i+\Delta x)-f(x_i)=0$ for all $n.$

This isn't the approach taken in the solution manual, but the actual solution seems to be missing some details. One odd peculiarity is that there's no mention of the Archimedean property, which I rely on. I know the end is dubious at best.

Comment: Where does the inequality$$\frac{f(x_i+\Delta x)-f(x_i)}{(y-x)^2}\le\frac1{n^2}$$come from?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos We have that $\Delta x= (y-x)/n.$ Since $f(x_i+\Delta x) - f(x_i) \le \Delta x^2,$ then, $f(x_i+\Delta x) - f(x_i) \le (y-x)^2/n^2.$ Dividing by $(y-x)^2$ gives the inequality.

Comment: The problem with your proof is that $f(x_i + \Delta x) - f(x_i)$ depends on $n$, in both the definitions of $\Delta x$ and of $x_i$. The Archimedean property asserts the existence of an $n$ greater than some fixed value, not the existence of an $n > g(n)$ for functions $g$. This problem is fixable. By summing $$f(x_i + \Delta x) - f(x_i) = f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)$$ you can arrive at an inequality where one side does not depend on $n$.